# download XML-File android error

Tags: android

I am developing an android app, and i need to download some simple XML-Files with authorization from an url. I already got something working in java on my local computer [Code at the end]. When i try to use this function in my android app, LogCat throws thousands of errors. I included Internet permission, i will attach the errors to my post.
So, heres my download function. i hardcoded the base64 string, because it will not change with the time...:

```
    public String getXmlFromUri(String url)
{
    String strFileContents = new String("");
    try{
        String base64 = "Basic " + "hardcodedBase64String";
        URL pURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = pURL.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", base64);
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String data = new String("");
        while((data = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            strFileContents += data;
        }
        in.close();
    }catch(IOException e)       {}
        if(strFileContents == "") strFileContents = "An error occured or the downloaded file was empty!";
    return strFileContents;
}
```

My logcat is very long, so i uploaded it at pastebin: http://pastebin.com/DhFra9SG

The function isnt finished yes, and I am currently only using it on the website where i need authorization.

To conclude: It works on windows, and it does not work on android! 
it

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:
`FATAL EXCEPTION: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

It crashes because you are trying to perform a network operation on UI (main) thread.
Network operations are considered to be long running operations and as a consequence they could block the UI. Thus, starting with API Level 11 if you attempt to perform a network operation on main thread, this exception is thrown.

Long running operations should run in a separate thread, for example you may use the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to get the XML file from the server.

Comment: This is true as of Honeycomb (3.0).  So, bear that in mind. The main thread is less restricted in older versions of Android.

Comment: So I changed my code:  http://pastebin.com/WG0k9Lne
and now I get these errors: http://pastebin.com/UB0WTY8a
Output ends at "2", so the function crashes at InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); as marked. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I got it working, had to delete the Console(String) calls... it's not allowed to do this :P silly android makes little me very very angry :D

Answer (score 0):

Based in your last piece of code and logcat the issue comes from the call of the Console method.

> Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
>   Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

Actually, you can not change/add some View object from the doInBackground method. If you want to change the UI, it must be from the onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result) and onProgressUpdate(Progress...) methods.

Check the **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** reference, and more specifically **The 4 steps section**.

BR